# Create a blank line/description line in quote line items

Tags: quote, quotelineitem, quote-template

I have been doing research and I haven't seen anyone post this as a question or answer it anywhere and I can't be the only person who wants to do this. I want to add in either blank lines or description lines to help organize our quotes in the quote line items but haven't found a good way to do it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hi skottyp, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to take the [tour] and read [ask]. I don't find your question very clear. Perhaps if you add a screenshot, that will help.

Comment: You seem to be having a bit of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. Your solution idea is going to be way more complex than simply building out a `Visualforce Page` which you can embed. You'll need to use the `Quote` object's `ApexPages.StandardController`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thank you for your idea. I always try to use standard functionality first before development. VF might be the only way to go here, but I haven't seen anyone build this in VF either. Like I said I searched for this solution and haven't found one. I didn't say what I thought the solution should be, just what the end result needs to look like.

Answer (score 0):

`QuoteLineItem` has a required field: `PricebookEntryId` that points at a `Product2` and has a default unit price (including 0.00)

so, to stick with OOTB, you would need to create a special Product2 with ProductCode = '...' and Description = `****surgicalUnit***`. You could probably/might get away with a ProductCode with some UTF-8 value that doesn't display but that SFDC doesn't think is blank.

Otherwise, Adrian's suggestion for a custom related list on the Quote detail page is a place to go; but this means you run into issues with certain related lists that aren't available to VF (like Quote field history)